# c structs, pointer and memory allocation for fields

Tags: c

Suppose the following code:

```
struct c {
  char* name;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct c c1;
  c1.name = "Ana";
  printf ("%s\n",c1.name);
  return 0;
}
```

My first reaction would have been to think that I needed to allocate some space, either on the heap, or by an explicit `char name[] = "Anna"`, but my example above works. Is the compiler just storing that string in the Data segment and pointing to it? In other words, is that like doing a

```
struct c {
  char* name = "Ana";
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
struct c c1;
c1.name = "Ana";
```

You don't have allocate memory here because you are making the pointer `c1.name` point to a string literal and string literals have static storage duration.  This is NOT similar to:

```
char name[] = "Anna";
```

Because in this case memory is allocated to store the sting literal and then the string literal `"Anna"` is *copied* into the array `name` . What you do with the  struct assignment `c1.name = "Ana"` is similar to when you do:

```
char *name = "Anna";
```

i.e. make the pointer point to a string literal.

Comment: Alright, I think I get it. What clarified this is your "static storage duration", which means it's actually in the data segment at compile time, and then the compiler knows obviously where to point. Thanks.

Comment: Note that `char name[] = "Anna";` only works as an initialization, and not as assignment later. `struct a { char b[10]; };` would not require that memory for the `b` field to be manually allocated, but also would not allow for `struct a c; c.b = "Anna";` Instead you would need to use `strcpy`, `strncpy`, `strcat`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I am new to C but from what I think this could be just the same as

```
char *cThing;
cThing = "Things!";
```

where `printf("%s\n", cThing);` would then print "Things!", except you're declaring the pointer in a struct.

Comment: I'm giving you a victory point :) I find amazing that you had the intuition, and used a good simple example to communicate it. Well done :)